# WPF RadioButton inside ItemsControl IsChecked Binding Path

Tags: wpf, radio-button, itemscontrol

I am trying to bind a collection of object to Listbox which has a Item template defined for radio button.
In the radio button for IsChecked property i need the reference of the item source object that it is bind to..

**Sample Xmal:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ports}">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <RadioButton Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Port, Converter={StaticResource PortConverter}, ConverterParameter=ABC, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">ABC</RadioButton>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Sample Object:**

```
public class Port {

public string Name {get; set;}

}
```

**View Model:**

```
public IEnumerable< Port > Ports {get; set;}
```

Need some pointers to the same..

Comment: You need to provide more details... what do the bound objects look like?

Comment: Updated more details for model and view model..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the path from your bindings or give path as dot(.), it should work. I am assuming that code in your converter takes an object of type Port and based on some conditions you are returning bool value from there since Port is an object of a class and not a bool value.

```
<RadioButton Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource PortConverter}, ConverterParameter=ABC, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">ABC</RadioButton>
```

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment... actually the binding is not TwoWay ; I was misled by the fact that UpdateSourceTrigger was specified. Your answer is correct, +1 ;)